# Is there any way to sync the scrollbars in a JavaFX 1.2 ListView?

Tags: listview, scrollbar, javafx

I have multiple listviews sidebyside. I have a way to make sure the "selectedIndex" is the same on all of them, but is there a way to make it so the scrollbar's are ALWAYS synchronized?

It seems that the scrollbars WILL be synced as long as the user uses the ARROW KEYS when navigating down the listview, however, if the user HOLDS DOWN the key, OR USES THE MOUSE WHEEL, they will not be synchronized at all.

Comment: If you want to have two list views with selectedIndex always being the same and the scroll position always being the same what is stopping you from creating just a single list view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible, even in 1.3 there is no access to internal scrollbar and also there is any way how to set up custom scrollbar. If you can please file an issue against JavaFX Runtime describing your use-case. http://javafx-jira.kenai.com

Answer (score 0):

Old question but in case somebody is interested : I now use the class below (Tested in FX2.2) to synchronize the scrolling of 2 ListViews :

```
package fx.scrollbars;

import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollBar;

/**
 * Created by JRD on 03/03/2015.
 */
public class ScrollbarsBinding {

public static final int BIND_BIDIRECTIONAL = 3;
public static final int BIND_RIGHT_TO_LEFT = 1;
public static final int BIND_LEFT_TO_RIGHT = 2;

/**
 * Bidirectional binding of 2 ListView's scrollbars.
 */
public static void bind(ListView lv1, ListView lv2) {
    bind(lv1, lv2, BIND_BIDIRECTIONAL);
}

/**
 * Allows binding of 2 ListView's scrollbars.
 * @param lv1 left list view
 * @param lv2 right list view
 * @param bindType 3 binding possibilities : BIND_BIDIRECTIONAL=bidirectional, BIND_RIGHT_TO_LEFT and BIND_LEFT_TO_RIGHT
 */
public static void bind(ListView lv1, ListView lv2, int bindType) {
    ScrollBar bar1 = null;
    ScrollBar bar2 = null;

    for (Node node : lv1.lookupAll(".scroll-bar")) {
        if (node instanceof ScrollBar && ((ScrollBar)node).getOrientation().equals(Orientation.VERTICAL)) {
            bar1 = (ScrollBar)node;
        }
    }
    for (Node node : lv2.lookupAll(".scroll-bar")) {
        if (node instanceof ScrollBar && ((ScrollBar)node).getOrientation().equals(Orientation.VERTICAL)) {
            bar2 = (ScrollBar)node;
        }
    }
    if (bar1 == null || bar2 == null) return;

    final ScrollBar fbar1 = bar1;
    final ScrollBar fbar2 = bar2;
    if (fbar1 != null && (bindType & BIND_RIGHT_TO_LEFT) != 0) {
        fbar1.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
                fbar2.setValue(newValue.doubleValue());
            }
        });
    }
    if (fbar2 != null && (bindType & BIND_LEFT_TO_RIGHT) != 0) {
        fbar2.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
                fbar1.setValue(newValue.doubleValue());
            }
        });
    }
}

// TODO: other JavaFx components ?
}
```

Then I just have to call this code :

```
ScrollbarsBinding.bind(listView1, listView2);
```